# Jquery UI Modal Dialog doesnt let scroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-dialog

I have a tall form in my dialog, and it has to be modal. Now when I try to scroll down, it doesnt let me. Have a look

http://jsfiddle.net/JQWf4/61/

Irrelevant Code Below(stackoverflow asks for code before submission)

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
modal: true,
});
```

Is this the way it is supposed to be? I mean, are the modal forms supposed to be visible with in a page or can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modals should be like that... at least that's common... what I can suggest is you put a scroll on your modal content...

give it a height... like this

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
    modal: true,
    height: 300
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/JQWf4/62/)

Comment: this works, but i just found that it was actually a bug.
http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4671